# Неопределенность со StringComparison

Tags: c#, .net, строки, visual-studio

Есть задача написать метод, который проверяет есть ли символ в строке, но с усложнением и прогнать тесты

```
/// <summary>
/// Returns a value indicating whether a specified string occurs within this string, using the specified comparison rules.
/// </summary>
/// <returns>true if the <paramref name="value"/> parameter occurs within this string, or if <paramref name="value"/> is the <see cref="string.Empty"/>; otherwise, false.</returns>
public static bool IsContainsStringWithStringComparison(string str, string value)
{
    return str.Contains(value, StringComparison.CurrentCulture);
}
```

По тестам есть следующее

```
[TestCase("encyclopaedia", "enc", "en-US", ExpectedResult = true)]
[TestCase("encyclopaedia", "dia", "en-US", ExpectedResult = true)]
[TestCase("encyclopaedia", "fen", "en-US", ExpectedResult = false)]
[TestCase("encyclopaedia", "ENC", "en-US", ExpectedResult = false)]
[TestCase("ENCYCLOPAEDIA", "enc", "en-US", ExpectedResult = false)]
[TestCase("encyclopaedia", "pæd", "en-US", ExpectedResult = true)]
[TestCase("ENCYCLOPAEDIA", "PÆD", "en-US", ExpectedResult = true)]
[TestCase("encyclopaedia", "PÆD", "en-US", ExpectedResult = false)]
[TestCase("ENCYCLOPAEDIA", "pæd", "en-US", ExpectedResult = false)]
[TestCase("encyclopaedia", "pæd", "se-SE", ExpectedResult = true)]
[TestCase("ENCYCLOPAEDIA", "PÆD", "se-SE", ExpectedResult = true)]
[TestCase("encyclopaedia", "PÆD", "se-SE", ExpectedResult = false)]
[TestCase("ENCYCLOPAEDIA", "pæd", "se-SE", ExpectedResult = false)]
public bool IsContainsStringWithStringComparison(string str, string value, string culture)
{
    // Arrange
    CultureInfo currentCulture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
    CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(culture);

    try
    {
        // Act
        return Contains.IsContainsStringWithStringComparison(str, value);
    }
    finally
    {
        // Tear down
        CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = currentCulture;
    }
}
```

Так вот, тесты с особыми символами (æ, Æ) не работают как надо и выдают false, хотя как я понял StringComparison.CurrentCulture должен решать проблему.

Comment: А `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` и `StringComparison.CurrentCulture` - это разве одно и то же? Вы меняете первое, а используется в той функции второе.

Comment: Укажите используемую версию .NET.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Они всё сломали!

Ваш код прекрасно будет работать в .NET Framework и первых версиях .NET Core.
Однако, в .NET 5 перешли на ICU по умолчанию.
[Behavior changes when comparing strings on .NET 5+](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/string-comparison-net-5-plus).

Вероятно, самым простым способом будет использовать National Language Support.
[Use NLS instead of ICU](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/globalization-icu#use-nls-instead-of-icu).
Добавляем в файл проекта:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <RuntimeHostConfigurationOption Include="System.Globalization.UseNls" Value="true" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Или в файл runtimeconfig.json:

```
{
  "runtimeOptions": {
     "configProperties": {
       "System.Globalization.UseNls": true
      }
  }
}
```